# expand("%") sometimes gives me a full path

Tags: neovim, plugin-nvimtree

For some reason, some times the command `expand("%")` gives me a full path of a file rather than the relative path as expected.
If I check the `pwd` it says I'm on the project folder. However, going to NvimTree, navigating to the root of the folder and executing the CD mapping makes this problem go away.

Can this be related to my session loading plugin? How can I debug it?

Comment: Why do you expect `expand("%")` to give you a relative path?

Comment: because that is what it usually gives you unless you couple it with path modifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, `%` gives you a *downward-relative* path:

- if the file is relative to the working directory,
- *and* if it was edited with a downward-relative path.

So expecting `expand('%')` to always return a downward-relative path is a bit unreasonable.

Example:

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ vim
:edit README.md
:echo expand('%')
README.md
:edit /path/to/project/CONTRIBUTING.md
:echo expand('%')
/path/to/project/CONTRIBUTING.md
:edit ../project/LICENSE
:echo expand('%')
../project/LICENSE
```

But, supposing that you never knowingly edit a file with an absolute or upward-relative path, who knows what your navigation habits and/or your plugins do to them under the hood?

To *always* get a downward-relative path for files located under the working directory, no matter how you edited them, you would have to be more defensive:

```
expand('%:.')
```

See `:help filename-modifiers`.